# How to set the delay time for Google presentation slides without publishing it?

Tags: google-slides

I created a long Google presentation slideshow with pictures. I am able to change the transition speed, but when starting the presentation and clicking the play button, the delay for each slide is much too short. I can't believe there is no setting for that. Where is it?

The only official solution I could find is publishing the slideshow on the web for everyone. There you can choose the delay. But I don't want to publish it, it's just for my own use.

I assume that when I don't give the published link to anyone else, it's safe, but it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When publishing the presentation, you can see that a parameter `delayms` is added to the URL, with the time you selected, in milliseconds.

I just tried an idea and it also works with non-published presentations!

Take the URL from edit mode, replace everything from `/edit` with `/present?delayms=8000` and you get what you wanted.

Comment: The presentation will auto start too with `/present?delayms=8000&start=true`. You can also set the delay amount to anything you want. You are not limited to the preset options Google lists in their dropdown.